# What is the API rate limit of Update Group operation in MS Graph API?

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api

What is the API rate limit of [**Update Group**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) operation in MS Graph API ?

It is not clear from the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling

Comment: What is the scenario you are following or what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity we need the documented API rate limit for Update group operation

Answer (score 0):

The current rate limiting system is quite complex and this is one of the reasons why it's not documented today. We're working on new mechanisms that should roll out in the next few months.
Once those mechanisms are deployed, the new limits will be on the page you referenced.
You can see the documentation work in progress here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/8451